# Temp postgres table ignores "excluding constraints"

Tags: postgresql, temporary-tables

In PostgreSQL 9.5.

I'd like to create a temporary copy of my table without its primary key. Postgres has a feature `{ INCLUDING | EXCLUDING } { DEFAULTS | CONSTRAINTS | INDEXES | STORAGE | COMMENTS | ALL }` - which I'm attempting to use.

```
create table test (
    col1    integer,
    col2    integer,
    col3    text,
    primary key (col1)
);

create temporary table t (like test excluding constraints);

insert into t (col1, col2, col3) values (1, 2, 'foo'), (null, 2, 'bar');
```

If I'm understanding `excluding constraints` correctly, that should not bring over the non-null constraint on `test` to `t`.

But here's the error that I receive:

```
ERROR:  null value in column "col1" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, 2, bar).
********** Error **********

ERROR: null value in column "col1" violates not-null constraint
SQL state: 23502
Detail: Failing row contains (null, 2, bar).
```

I have a workaround, `create temporary table t as select * from test where true = false`, but I'd like to know what I'm not understanding correctly about `excluding constraints`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'd like to know what I'm not understanding correctly about `excluding constraints`.

What is happening here is that `primary key (col1)` creates a `primary key` constraint but doesn't create a separate `not null` constraint. It adds a `not null` "modifier" to the column. This works as a constraint, ie. no nulls are allowed in `col1` but it is not a named constraint. That's why it's not removed by the `excluding constraints`, it's a column property.

As the [`CREATE TABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html) documentation states:

> Not-null constraints are always copied to the new table. `CHECK` constraints will be copied only if `INCLUDING CONSTRAINTS` is specified. ..

If you had the table defined with an explicit `CHECK column is not null` constraint instead:

```
create table test (
    col1    integer,
    col2    integer,
    col3    text,
    unique (col1),
    check (col1 is not null)
);
```

then the `excluding constraints` would have succeeded. But if the table has a `primary key` defined, then all the columns of this primary key are created with the `not null` modifier and a `create .. like test` will copy these modifiers.

Your workaround is valid. Either of these will work:

```
create temporary table t as select * from test where false ;
create temporary table t as select * from test limit 0 ;
```

Comment: Spot on. The syntax for the workaround can be even simpler: `CREATE TEMP TABLE t AS TABLE test LIMIT 0;`

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter What does the `where false` or `limit 0` exactly do in this context from the workaround? I mean i see what it does, but why?

Comment: @FireEmerald: To exclude all rows, i.e. create an empty temp table.